# jQuery get the input value in an .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am trying to get the input value in an each loop of a checkbox, i cant figure out how to get this to work, the value keeps outputting as the first checkbox value.

```
$('.custemb, input[name=cb], input[class=multadd]').live("click", function() {

    $('input[class=multadd]:checked').each(function(index) {
        val = index + 2;
        valu = $('input[class=multadd]:checked').val();
        multiz = multiz + '&aid' + val + '=' + valu;
    });
});
```

the problem is the output of the variable `valu` is the first checkbox of the overall each loop, not the current checkbox of the loop, i need the current value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use `this` to access the current element in the loop:

```
valu = $(this).val();
```

The current element is also sent as a parameter to the callback function, so you can pick it up:

```
.each(function(index, elem) {
```

Then use the parameter:

```
valu = $(elem).val();
```

Comment: I would like to ask why do I have to use the selector on "elem" to access to the value if "elem" is already the input element? Thanks

Comment: @mkmnstr: Because `elem` is the element, not a jQuery object for the element. The `$()` function takes different kinds of parameters, not only selectors. If you send in an element it will simply create a jQuery object containing that element. The call `$(this)` in the first example uses the function in the same way.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, is all clear now! Cheers!

Comment: @Guffa What if one of the elements is a radio, using `.each(function(index, elem) {` how do I get the selected radio using elem object?

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x: You can use `$(elem).is(':radio')` to check if the element is a radio button, and `$(elem).is(':checked')` to check if it is selected. You can combine them as `$(elem).is(':radio:checked')`.

Comment: How do you set value instead of get

Comment: how do you know which input the value is coming from I mean if I just want the value of one the value of the other one separately?

Comment: @dave: The code in the question collects the values from the checked checkboxes. If you want to know if a specific checkbox is checked you can test that directly, for example using `var checked = $('input[name=cb]').is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.custemb, input[name=cb], input[class=multadd]').live("click", function() {

    $('input[class=multadd]:checked').each(function(index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        val = index + 2;
        valu = $this.val();
        multiz = multiz + '&aid' + val + '=' + valu;
    });
});
```

Comment: `.each()` offers a second parameter `element` which is an alternative to `this`

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair which would probably save one lookup and microincrease performance. Good call, mate

Comment: you didn't get it ... using the second parameter you can (in other scenarious) extract the method for the each-iteration and therefore maybe create a magically reusage scenario ...

Answer (score 5):

```
var texts= $(".class_name").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();         
}).get();
```

Comment: why the need of the .get() ? its a AJAX function.

Answer (score 3):

Use `this` to find the control that was clicked

```
$('input[class=multadd]:checked').each(function(index) {
        val = index + 2;
        valu = $(this).val();
        multiz = multiz + '&aid' + val + '=' + valu;
    });
```