# Deserialize JSON hashset in controller ASP.NET to hashset or dictionary

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I have a function on the button (that works) I form HashSet of JSON objects priceWorkData with key/value pair. I mean many simply pairs of key/value like {1,11;2,12,55,67;44,77}.  I pass it as a JSON object to the controller but I can not deserialize this HashSet correctly. I want to get a list or dictionary of pairs in the controller.

```
function CalculateWorkHand(act) {

            var mySet = new Set();

        $(".PriceWork").each(function ()
        {
            var ValuePrice = this.value;
            var Id = this.id
            var o = {id: this.id, ValuePrice: this.value};
            mySet.add(o);

        });
        var pricejson = {mySet: mySet };

    $.ajax({  
       url: '@Url.Action("CalculateWorkHandJSON", "Acts")',       
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "pricejson": JSON.stringify(pricejson),"id":act},
        success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                  alert("Success");
                 }
                else {
                 alert("Data Error");
                }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
              //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
             alert("Error AJAX");
         }
      });
  };

       public class SelectedJournal
        {
            // [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
            //  [JsonProperty("value")]
            public string ValuePrice { get; set; }
        }


       public ActionResult CalculateWorkHandJSON(int id, string pricejson)
        {
            Act act = db.Act.Find(id);    
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();         
            List<SelectedJournal> deserializedResult = serializer.Deserialize<List<SelectedJournal>>(pricejson);           
            var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SelectedJournal>>(pricejson);

       ..........
        return ...;

        }
```

> I get error 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[projectofstack.Controllers.ActsController+SelectedJournal]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'priceWorkData', line 1, position 17.'

Comment: Can you please show me your `pricejson` string? I just came online now so I can help you deserialize your string. You can try this also: `var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(pricejson);` . Once you parse this correctly, you can access your variables in the parsed `temp` string

Comment: But how? I already put this in question. I do not form it manually but in .each fucntion   $(".PriceWork").each(function ()
            {
                var ValuePrice = this.value;
                var Id = this.id
                priceWorkData[Id] = ValuePrice;
                // alert(priceWorkData[this.id])

            });

            var pricejson = {
                          priceWorkData: priceWorkData
                         };

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code and check if you are able to hit `CalculateWorkHandJSON` method? You can navigate to your `pricejson` and see what values to do you receive there.

Comment: ok, but how? cause they in javascript. i get nulls when set breakpoint in controller function

Comment: From the looks of it, your `function CalculateWorkHand(act)` is not receving the values for `itemID` and `itemPrice`. You would need to get your values in your function. In these two lines: `var ValuePrice = //get value here;var Id = //Get value here`. You can refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668623/jquery-get-the-input-value-in-an-each-loop

Comment: of course it is not receives value cause I send them as json data creating in that js.code and want to convert to string and then int hashset and then work with them. I already have jsonstring with json hash

Comment: CalculateWorkHand(act)  did not receave values. It creats it from .each and I saw all of them by simply alerting. It works and forms hashset

Comment: I need to ask you two things: 1) Are you able to get your values in your `priceWorkData` when you do `console.log(priceWorkData)`. 2) If you are getting values in your `priceWorkData` string, then are you able to hit your `CalculateWorkHandJSON ` method? If you are hitting this method, then what value do you see there?

Comment: I do notknow how to use console.log. I use alert (value) and it works. What means hit method?

Comment: Okay, what you need to do is where you have written `alert`, below that type: `console.log(priceWorkData)`. Then refresh your page and hit `F12` to open up the developer console of your web browser. There under the `Console` category, you will see your printed `priceWorkData` string. Let me know what you see there

Comment: strange  information

Comment: console.log(priceWorkData[this.id]) outputs reasonable values but i find error. it only saves unique values but when output this.id and console.log(priceWorkData[this.id]) it works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202629/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-ifooi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your case, since you are generating a `Set`, you would need to send it correctly to your `Controller` method. You need to make the following changes:

In your AJAX call, change this line `data: { "pricejson": JSON.stringify(pricejson),"id":act}` to `data: { "pricejson": JSON.stringify([...mySet]),"id":act}`

Basically you would need to send a `string` representation of your set and then send it to your `Controller`. Once you recieve your values in your controller method, you can deserialize it: `var deserializedResult = serializer.Deserialize<List<SelectedJournal>>(pricejson);`